# PHP for sending a email from a form returns a T_STRING error

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

So, I got bored and decided to try out making a simple PHP form to send an email with form data. But now, it keeps returning the same error and it's really aggravating. Here's the form info:

```
<table class="table-1" cellspacing="5">
   <tr>
       <td><label for=fullname>Full Name</label></td> <td><input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="First and Last Name" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label for=email>Email</label></td> <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@something.com" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label>Age</label></td>
       <td>
           <select name="age">
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="160">160</option>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label>Are you a programmer/developer?</label></td>
       <td>
           <select name="program-q">
              <option value="yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="no">No</option>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label for=picUrl>Picture?</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="picUrl" placeholder="URL of your Image" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label>Are you an <a href="http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Otaku" target="_blank">Otaku?</a></label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="otaku-yes" /> Yes </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label>Do you like JROCK/JPOP?</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="jrock-yes" /> <label for=jrock-yes>Heck yeah!</label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><label>Would you dress up like a maid randomly<br /> and call me 'master' all day?</label></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="maid-q" /> <label for=maid-q>Why Not? ;D </label></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Apply Now!" /></td>
   </tr>
```

That part works fine, and then this is the PHP:

```
<?php
    $to = "jake@weeshare.ws";
    $subject = "New Submission";
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $programmer = $_POST['program-q'];
    $picUrl = $_POST['picUrl'];
    $otaku = $_POST['otaku-yes'];
    $jrock = $_POST['jrock-yes'];
    $maid = $_POST['maid-q'];
    $headers = "From: $email";
    $sent = mail("$to, \n $subject, \n $fullname, \n $age, \n $programmer, \n $picUrl, \n $otaku, \n $jrock, \n $maid);
    if ( $sent ) {
       echo "Good.";
    } else {
       echo "Not good.";
    }

?>
```

Everytime I click 'Submit,' this is what it returns. No matter how many times I've tweaked it, my server just keeps sending this:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/weeshare/public_html/wtf/contact.php on line 15**

Any ideas on what's wrong? I've been at this for hours now and still nothing is working..

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"` at the end of the `mail()` call argument.

I suggest using an editor which does syntax highlighting, it makes this sort of error easy to spot.

Also see [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092277#18092277)

And as Michael Berkowski points out, your `mail()` call is wrong, get rid of the quotes and the `\n`.

Comment: No mention of the fact that the `mail()` call is nonsense? `mail()` takes several arguments, not one big string.

Comment: `mail()` should look like `mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers_separated_by\r\n)`

Comment: Yes -_- I'm sorry if it's horrendous, I've never really been a PHP person, so I decided to try this for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting here on SO should give you an idea of what's gone wrong! Perhaps you meant something more along the lines of this (N.B. removed $headers and modified mail() call):

```
$to = "jake@weeshare.ws";
$subject = "New Submission";
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$programmer = $_POST['program-q'];
$picUrl = $_POST['picUrl'];
$otaku = $_POST['otaku-yes'];
$jrock = $_POST['jrock-yes'];
$maid = $_POST['maid-q'];

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $fullname . ' ' . $age . ' ' . $programmer . ' ' . $picUrl . ' ' . $otaku . ' ' . $jrock . ' ' . $maid);

if($sent) {
    echo "Good.";
}
else {
    echo "Not good.";
}
```